# Jmeter tests out of memory error even for high heap size allocation

Tags: java, memory, jmeter, performance-testing

i am running some performance tests with Jmeter 5.0.
parsing a csv file with my parameters and sending a simple post request, nothing special.
100 threads configured in my thread group concurrency with 100 RPS(not a lot).
heap size set to max 15GB and min 1GB.
my machine physical RAM memory is 32GB.
i have tried to raise the heap size to 20GB and even 25GB but it still crashed due to lack of memory.
i have analyzed the gc logs and saw that for the first 15GB max heap size configuration and for the second most of the heap size (about 95%) is in use by the old generation, somehow the GC in unable to clean them.
i am not using GUI mode and non of the listeners.
the first 15GB configuration crashed after 1 hour and 20 minutes, the second lasted for just more than 2 hours.

here is the GCeasy log analysis for the 20GB:
[20GB heap size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiaBj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say anything meaningful without seeing:

1. The full stacktrace (because [OutOfMemory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) may have many faces)
2. The contents of your [HProf file](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033184011-KBEC-00423-How-to-configure-HPROF-files-and-generation-and-details-on-how-to-Analyze-Hprof-files)
3. The structure of your test plan

In general OutOfMemory error indicates a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), so make sure to follow recommendations from the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article.

---

A "blind shot". You can have 100 RPS with 100 virtual users only if your application response time is 1 second or less.

If application response time becomes > 1 second and you're using [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) in order to force JMeter to reach 100 TPS, it might be the case the application simply cannot respond faster due to being overloaded and JMeter adds more and more threads trying to reach 100 RPS until it runs out of the resources.

Comment: the application response time is not stable, it may reach more than 1 second rarely, but its possible. can you suggest a static timer to hold this number of threads?. i have already tried all the solutions provided in this article.

Comment: I would go for the combination of [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) with Throughput Shaping Timer [combination](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) and also consider using [AutoStop Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right/) in order to stop the test if application response time exceeds the maximum acceptable threshold.

Comment: yes, i am using Throughput Shaping Timer to reach this rate. it fails to allocate new native thread so the point you mentioned might be the issue.

Comment: i am already using the combination of both, while my Target Conccurency is configured to be ${__tstFeedback(RPS,10,100,20)}. when RPS is the name of the timer.